# How do I deploy to a new Remote Machine?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, there is no obvious place to change the IP address for a "Remove Machine" build, once the initial pop-up has asked you for the remote address.

How do you change the deploy address?

Answer (score 0):

Window > Solution Explorer.
Right-click the Project (not the solution) and select Properties.
In the Debug Tab select "All Configurations"